# Open specific conversation on whatsapp from ionic 4

Tags: whatsapp, ionic4

I have tried to call whatsapp from InAppBrowser plugin by passing url "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+91123456890&text=test".
I have also added config.xml changes as suggested
(access launch-external="yes" origin="whatsapp:*" /)

It opens the browser (when I run this on device) with send button on it to send the message to Whatsapp.

But I am unable to tap the Send button. It is not redirecting me to whatsapp application with given number.

Please can you show me some sample code or the way to achieve this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

i also face this problem. following code fixed my problem

```
 window.open('whatsapp://send?phone=923130601266', '_system');
```

Answer (score 0):

> You should try to call below api in InAppBrowser.

The direct conversation will open with the number you set below the link.

**Don't forget to add country code before number.**

https://wa.me/your-mobile-number